# Install trouble for Android SDK in Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation

EDIT: I fixed it by not installing the NDK Development stuff. I don't know what it is, or what it does, but it fixed my problem.

I'm on Windows 64-bit, using Eclipse Helios, and trying to install the latest Android SDK. So far, I've been able to download and install the SDK Manager and successfully ran through its stuff.

The trouble comes in when I try to install inside of Eclipse (Help -> Install New Software). Every time I try to install using either the URL address (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) or the .zip file I get this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, >     phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

The internet doesn't seem to have any answers that I can find. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the conversation...

But I have found this error when trying to install packages, not at all associated with Android, from older Eclipse versions, which by now includes Helios.  It actually took me a while to figure out all those Eclipse project names are actually versions.  At the time of this writing, Eclipse Kepler is the latest, once I upgraded (pretty much a fresh install) to Kepler and tried again to install the packages, everything worked fine.

Hopes this is helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse as administrator and install Android SDK.

You must use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ for SDK installation.

See [Install ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

By the way, which version of java are you using? I reckon the error is possibly an eclipse bug, related to Java 1.7.

Try JRE 1.6 and see if it works!

Comment: I'm using JRE7. I tried running as administrator and it seems to be stuck with the same error, but it's just continuously running anyways.

Comment: I think it is an eclipse bug. which version of java are you using?

Comment: I fixed it by not installed the NDK.

Comment: Ran into the same issue when suddenly Eclipse refused to install ADT updates over the SSL link. Updated to the http one without SSL, then the NDK refused to install, as @Braains said. I don't need it, so I am also skipping that installation, but this whole thing is such a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following tool for starting the android devolopment
(1) Eclipse ide
(2) ADT for eclipse (android plugin for eclipse)
(3) Android SDK

You get a brief idea about each of these steps from the following link
  http://codeglympse.blogspot.in/2012/10/installing-eclipse-and-android-sdk.html